# Error while running selenium ide exported script in python on FF browser

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Im new to selenium & python.
I have installed python 3.4.1 & selenium webdriver. Created  script using selenium ide and exported to python webdriver.
Firefox version - 31.0
System configuration : Window - 32 bit

Script :
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
    from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
    import unittest, time, re

```
class Test(unittest.TestCase):
def setUp(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
    self.base_url = "https://www.gmail.com/"
    self.verificationErrors = []
    self.accept_next_alert = True

def test_(self):
    driver = self.driver
    driver.get(self.base_url)
    driver.find_element_by_id("Email").clear()
    driver.find_element_by_id("Email").send_keys("shivart")
    driver.find_element_by_id("Passwd").clear()
    driver.find_element_by_id("Passwd").send_keys("test12")
    driver.find_element_by_id("signIn").click()
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.gb_2").click()
    driver.find_element_by_id("gb_71").click()

def is_element_present(self, how, what):
    try: self.driver.find_element(by=how, value=what)
    except NoSuchElementException as e: return False
    return True

def is_alert_present(self):
    try: self.driver.switch_to_alert()
    except NoAlertPresentException as e: return False
    return True

def close_alert_and_get_its_text(self):
    try:
        alert = self.driver.switch_to_alert()
        alert_text = alert.text
        if self.accept_next_alert:
            alert.accept()
        else:
            alert.dismiss()
        return alert_text
    finally: self.accept_next_alert = True

#def tearDown(self):
#    self.driver.quit()
 #   self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)

if __name__ == "__main__":
unittest.main()
```

when running the script i get below error.

Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "C:\test.py", line 20, in test_
         driver.find_element_by_id("Email").send_keys("shivart.rt")
        File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py",
          line 293, in send_keys
         self._execute(Command.SEND_KEYS_TO_ELEMENT, {'value': typing})

```
 File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py",
  line 370, in _execute
return self._parent.execute(command, params)
```

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", l
   ine 173, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)

```
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py"
, line 164, in check_response
 raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
```

selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'Component returned fail
   ure code: 0x80004003 (NS_ERROR_INVALID_POINTER) [nsINativeKeyboard.sendKeys]'

Comment: Please include the script in your question and format your error message so that it is easy to read.

Comment: I have tried running same script in windows 64 bit on FF and it works without throwing any error .